# Обработка событий с одинаковыми ID

Tags: jquery, поиск

Сделал незамысловатый живой поиск, и обработку перехода по списку по стрелкам вверх/вниз. Проблема в том, что по первому кругу всё проходит нормально, но если вернуться повторно в поле, то стрелочки начинают срабатывать через одну/две/и т.д. в зависимости от пройденных полей. В чем моя ошибка? Я уже пробовал задавать id в виде partn1..n pul1..n. 
Не понимаю работы JQ, если я обращаюсь по текущему this элементу, то почему на него влияют остальные текстовые поля???

И еще, как следствие, по Enter тоже начинает криво срабатывать, поле просто очищается.

```js
$('tr[id^=add]').on("focus",'#partn',function(){
$partn = $(this);
$pul = $(this).next().first();
$pul.find('li').first().addClass('act');
$pul.fadeIn();   
var inp = document.getElementById('partn');
inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) e.preventDefault();
}, false);
$partn.on("keyup", function(e) {
     switch (e.keyCode) {
     case 38:
  $lc = $pul.find('li:visible').last();
        $fc = $pul.find('li:visible').first();
  if($fc.hasClass('act'))
  {$fc.removeClass('act');
      $lc.addClass('act');
  } else
  {
   $ac = $pul.find('li.act');
   $ac.removeClass('act').prevAll(':visible:not(div)').first().addClass('act');
  }
  break;
  case 40:
  $lc = $pul.find('li:visible').last();
        $fc = $pul.find('li:visible').first();
  if($lc.hasClass('act'))
  {$lc.removeClass('act');
      $fc.addClass('act');
  } else
  {
   $ac = $pul.find('li.act');
   $ac.removeClass('act').nextAll(':visible:not(div)').first().addClass('act');
  }
  break;
  case 13:
  $ac = $pul.find('li.act');
  $(this).val($ac.text());
  $ac.removeClass('act');
  $pul.fadeOut();
  break;
  case 39:
  case 41:
  break;
  default:
  
  if(!($pul).is(':visible')) $pul.fadeIn();
  $val = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
          $pul.find('li').each(function() {
    $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf($val)==-1?$(this).hide():$(this).show();
    if($(this).hasClass('act')) $(this).removeClass('act');
    });
  $pul.find('li:visible').first().addClass("act");
  break;
  }
  
});
 $pul.on("click", "li", function(){
     $partn.val($(this).text());
  $pul.find('li.act').removeClass('act');
     $pul.fadeOut();
});  
});
$('tr[id^=add]').on("focusout",'#partn',function(){
 $pul = $(this).next().first();
 $pul.find('li.act').removeClass('act');
 $pul.fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#pul {
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 z-index:109;
 background: #FFF;
 margin-top:2px;
     border: 1px #ccc solid;
     border-radius: 4px;
     max-height:200px;
}
#pul div {
 display:block;
 font-size:0.9rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#eee;
}
#pul li {
     list-style: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding:2px 2px 2px 10px;
     border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition:0.3s; 
}
li.act {
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
 color:#fff;  
}
#pul li:hover{
     background: #5a86d5;
  color:#fff;
 }
#ul li:hover {
    background-color: #eee; 
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id=add1><td><input type=text id=partn />
    <ul id=pul>
      <li>opt 1</li>
      <li>apt 2</li>
      <li>upt 3</li>
      <li>cpt 4</li>
      <li>ppt 5</li>
    </ul>
    </td></tr>
  <tr id=add2><td><input type=text id=partn />
    <ul id=pul>
      <li>opt 1</li>
      <li>apt 2</li>
      <li>upt 3</li>
      <li>cpt 4</li>
      <li>ppt 5</li>
    </ul>
    </td></tr>
  <tr id=add3><td><input type=text id=partn />
    <ul id=pul>
      <li>opt 1</li>
      <li>apt 2</li>
      <li>upt 3</li>
      <li>cpt 4</li>
      <li>ppt 5</li>
    </ul>
    </td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не назначайте обработчики событий

`inp.addEventListener("keydown", ...`

и

`$partn.on("keyup", ...`

внутри других обработчиков событий

`$('tr[id^=add]').on("focus",'#partn', ...`

Они накапливаются и выполняются столько раз, сколько раз были назначены.

Ну и конечно, повторяющиеся `id` на странице - это грех. Используйте `class`.